# [programming-languages]: Burninate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [programming-languages](/questions/tagged/programming-languages) tag seems to be useless on Meta.

It has 10 questions and only 4 are still open.

And those 4 could live without it, as they don't add anything at all.

Comment: Only 10? Just edit the posts, remove the tag. Job done.

Comment: OK, done. Removed... it is now a zombie tag and will get cleaned up.

Comment: @Oded lol... ok. [tag:status-completed]? :)

Comment: I suppose so ;)

Comment: @Oded BTW some of the posts that you just edited had some close votes on them - mind using your mod power? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]